# Does Inkscape's --vacuum-defs make SVGs truly safe?

Tags: security, svg

We are considering allowing user uploaded SVGs in our web app. We've been hesitant to do this before, due to a large number of complex vulnerabilities that we know exist in untrusted SVGs. A coworker found the --vacuum-defs option to Inkscape, and believes that it renders all untrusted SVGS safe for processing.

According to the manpage, that option "Removes all unused items from the  section of the SVG file. If this option is invoked in conjunction with --export-plain-svg, only the exported file will be affected. If it is used alone, the specified file will be modified in place." However, according to my coworker, "Scripting is removed, XML transformations are removed, malformations are not tolerated, encoding is removed and external imports are removed.

Is this true? If so, is it enough that we should feel safe accepting untrusted SVGs? Is there any other preprocessing we should do?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the main concern of serving untrusted SVGs is the fact that SVG files can contain Javascript. This is obvious for SVG because embedded javascript is part of the format, but it can happen with every type of uploaded file if the browser is not careful.

Therefore, and even though modern browsers do not execute scripts found in the < img > tags, just in case I think it's good to serve the images from a different domain with no cookies/auth attached to it, so that any executed script will not compromise users' data. That would be my first concern.

Of course if the user downloads the SVG and then opens it from the desktop and happens to open it with the browser, it might execute the potentially malicious load. So back to the original question, --export-plain-svg does remove scripting, but as I don't know of other SVG-specific vulnerabilites, I haven't checked for them.